# Convert lower case characters to capitals and capitals to lower case

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert the lower case of a given string to capital letters and the capital letters to lower case letters.

For example: Initial string: `Hello World!` and the resulting output must be  `hELLO wORLD!`.

My current code is:

```
# Ask the use to give a string
user_string = input("Please give a string: ")
new_string = user_string

# For each character in the given string
    # Check if it is a capital letter and convert it to lower case.
    # Check if it is a lower case letter and convert it to capital.

for char in user_string:
    if char.islower():
       new_string[char]=
    if char.isupper():
```

Comment: documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=upper#str.upper)

Comment: TL;DR - `new_string = user_string.swapcase()`

Comment: For future questions, don't forget to add what the problem is with your code. So we don't have to guess.